# How to save the file after typing "crontab -e"

Tags: cron

I open the file in terminal through `crontab -e` command and now I want to save it. I've tried several things, like `:wq` or <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd>, but it did not save the file. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have any content in the file before you :wq? Otherwise it will not create a file.

Comment: Actually i have a email script in my Console/Command directory in cakephp and i followed a tutorial and according to this i want to set time for this email script through cron but do not know how to do this? can you explain a bit please?

Comment: This question seems to be just about saving the crontab in the editor invoked by `crontab -e`, and you've gotten two answers to that. If your question is just "How do I use crontab?", I suggest reading the documentation; if you have *specific* questions after that, post them separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `crontab -e` command invokes your default editor, which is one of the following:

- The command specified by the `$VISUAL` environment variable (if it's set); or
- The command specified by `$EDITOR`; or
- `/usr/bin/editor`

The latter is a symbolic link to *some* editor. On Linux, the default appears to be `nano`.

If it's `nano`, then there should be a 2-line menu at the bottom of the screen. Type <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> to exit; if you've modified the file it will ask you whether you want to save it.

If you have a preferred editor, you should set both `$VISUAL` and `$EDITOR` to the command used to invoke it.  For example, I have:

```
export EDITOR=vi
export VISUAL=$EDITOR
```

in my `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

This applies to the system I'm using, a recent Linux system with the Vixie cron implementation. If your system differs significantly, not all of this is necessarily applicable.

`man crontab` should explain how the `crontab` command works. If not, the documentation is also [available here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab).

(Incidentally, I keep my crontab in a separate file under my home directory, maintained in a source control system. That lets me keep track of changes and revert to a working version if I mess something up. With `crontab -e`, it's easy to make mistakes and difficult to recover from them.)

Comment: Actually i have a email script in my Console/Command directory in cakephp and i followed a tutorial and according to this i want to set time for this email script through cron but do not know how to do this? can you explain a bit please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your editor variable:

```
$ EDITOR=vi
$ export EDITOR
$ crontab -e
```

Of course if vi isn't your editor, change it accordingly.